# AD Domain Login to ESXi Host - Permission to Perform this Operation Denied

Tags: vmware, active-directory, vcenter

I'm grasping at straws at this point and hoping someone can help me out.

I have vCenter managing several ESXi hosts in remote locations. Lockdown mode is not enabled. vCenter and the ESXi hosts are joined to our AD domain. Domain login for vCenter works fine. Privileges are assigned to children.

If I try to login directly to the ESXi host's web client, I get the error:

> Permission to perform this operation was denied.

I can't find anything online related to this error using domain credentials. Local accounts work fine, domain privileges are granted from vCenter to all children (I tried assigning them directly to the host and children as well). Lockdown mode is not enabled.

Any idea why it's denying me access to login using domain credentials?

Answer (score 1):

Try logging into your host as root. Select the "Host" in the navigator menu on the left hand side.
Select

> Actions -> Permissions -> Add user

Within this menu, add the group you are part of including the domain i.e. `domain\group` and give the group a role.

Once the permission has been granted through this menu, you should be able to log into your host using your domain credentials.